# Data Masking in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data-masking

i want to display confidential data like *bank account number*, *mobile numbers* in `123**********1232`  format in **ASP.net** controls. Like `022-23232-2322` will be `022*********2322` and on update it should save the actual data entered.

How it would be achieved in ASP.net?

Comment: So this form is to update the  bank account number or mobile numbers and you want to mask it while the user types it?

Comment: only authorized users will un-mask it on update. for all other users , it will be masked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to mask it only for users which can't update it as commented, it's simple:

```
Dim number = "022-23232-2322" 
Dim token = number.split("-"c)
Dim masked = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", token(0), New String("*"c, 9), token.last())
```

Result as dersired: `022*********2322`

Of course you have to store the real number serverside or load it from database when you need it. You should never need to unmask it. If an authorized user wants to update it you get the new value and you don't need the old. If you need it reload it from the data-source.

Comment: thanks @Tim. you are right , it would be better to load it from database when needed.but what if i save the real number in session. is that a good approach ?

Comment: @Abdul: you could do that, it's not unsecure per se, but why do you need it? Normally you only need to identify the user via `UserID` (f.e. a `Guid` or something like that). You can get the back-account-number with that ID if you need it. If you just want to update it you only need that ID + the new number.

Comment: Yes , but i need this at several locations in my application. Thanks for the help @Tim  :)